# Angularjs Price slider is going out of range when ng-model is null or less than minimum value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, input, slider

I have an rz-slider on my page. It is used for getting the price of a product from user. Along with the slider I have two input fields, which is used to store the min and max values. the ng-model for the min and max input fields are same as the rz-slider-model and rz-slider-high respectively.

**The problem is, when ever I change the min or max input field to 0 the slider is going out of range. Is there any way to limit my slider in the specified range?**

```
<input type="number" min="1000" max="5000" ng-model= "priceSlider.min"> to
    <input type="number" min="1000" max="5000" ng-model= "priceSlider.max">
    <rzslider
        rz-slider-floor="priceSlider.floor"
        rz-slider-ceil="priceSlider.ceil"
        rz-slider-model="priceSlider.min"
        rz-slider-high="priceSlider.max"
        rz-slider-step="{{priceSlider.step}}"></rzslider>
```

**See my Plunk** [for reference.](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lf9wMjUWGnUlUF999YyL?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-change` directive of angularjs to validate value of `min` and `max`.

```
<input type="number" min="1000" max="5000" ng-change="checkMin()" ng-model= "priceSlider.min"> to
<input type="number" min="1000" max="5000" ng-change="checkMax()" ng-model= "priceSlider.max">
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.checkMin = function() {
    if (typeof $scope.priceSlider.min === 'undefined' || $scope.priceSlider.min < 1000 || $scope.priceSlider.min > 5000) {
      $scope.priceSlider.min = 1000;
    }
  }
  $scope.checkMax = function() {
    if (typeof $scope.priceSlider.max === 'undefined' || $scope.priceSlider.max < 1000 || $scope.priceSlider.max > 5000) {
      $scope.priceSlider.max = 5000;
    }
  }
```

This option doesn't allow set value by text to say 3000 because when user edit input box, `ng-change` function called and if value is not in range then set to default value.

Check [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aSWtPvG7mPN9eGHHOcRf?p=preview) for details.

Other option

Use `ng-blur` but the issue with ng-blur is if user enter `0` then it allows to set that value and on `blur` event it set value to default if input is not in valid range.

Choose appropriate based on requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In this case, I am not able to change the values in input box. What I need is, I want to change the input box but the slider should not go out of range.